# Creating a URL that always opens in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url

If I want to ensure a URL, if clicked, will always open in Chrome (instead of the default browser) can I do that by modifying the header?

For example, I can get URLs that always open in Evernote, they start with evernote:///

Is this possible, for example to have something like chrome:///www.url.com

Comment: That part of the url is referred to as the "protocol"

Answer (score 16):

Google has official documentation on the Chrome iOS app’s URI scheme on its [developer website](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links).

Simply replace `http` with `googlechrome` and `https` with `googlechromes`. This means:

- `http://www.google.com/` becomes **`googlechrome://www.google.com/`**
- `https://apple.stackexchange.com/` becomes **`googlechromes://apple.stackexchange.com/`**

Previously, it supported an [x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com/) of `googlechrome-x-callback://`. This allowed the calling app to indicate its name and URI scheme to Chrome, which would show a back button in the address bar that closes the tab and invokes the specified URI. This feature was removed a few years ago when iOS 9 added the “Back to …” button in the status bar (but the URI scheme still works).

Comment: Note that this doesn't apply to Chrome for Mac.

Comment: Doesn't work in word

Answer (score 6):

On iOS:

```
googlechrome://www.example.com
```

Comment: That may work on iOS—I don't have Chrome on my iPhone—but it does not work for me on Mavericks.

Comment: I was about to say the same. How are you proposing this should work. Firstly on Mavericks if you click a link with this protocol or go to it in a web address. The OS asks you to select an app that can open it. Even when Chrome is selected chrome will try and open the URL `file:///googlechrome:///www.example.com` each time

Comment: @markhunte OP did not specify OS X or iOS, I've clarified that this is just for iOS

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Cheers saved me wasting more time trying to figure it out.

Comment: Is there a way to do it for Mac? Not working on Catalina either.